# Redis connection close

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, connect-redis

Im using connect-domain and connect-redis. Below code checks for redis cache in Redis database.

```
function redis_get(key, req, res) {
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.get(redisKey, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error in RedisDB");
    }
    else if (data == null) {
        // Calling external function
    }
    else {
        // Calling external function
    }
    redisClient.quit();  // Not working
});
```

}

When cache is not avaiable Im calling external function. I want redis connection to be closed once the cache check has been done. 
redisClient.quit() // Not working

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: @user87267867 can you tell me what error u r getting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working fine without any problem.So check your status reply in the quit method if you get status as 'OK' means that method is working fine.

```
 var redis=require('redis');
 var redisClient = redis.createClient();
 redisClient.get('name', function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
      console.log("Error in RedisDB");
    }
  else if (data == null) {
      console.log('null');
     }
   else {
       console.log(data);
   }
 redisClient.quit(redis.print); 
});
```